# include of google maps in xml fails?

Tags: android, xml, maps

I got a kind of working home made gps which is working.
Now I'm creating a new app again with google maps inside.

In my main I create
     `startActivity(new Intent(this, GpsLogger.class));`

this create my intent which goes ok. During the onCreate of the GpsLogger I do a 
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer);

there it crashes...  but when I comment the google maps part in the xml... it doesn't crash. But I don't have google aps inside ofcourse...

```
<code><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout_main" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">  


<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<!--<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|right"> 
    </TableLayout> -->
<TextView android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/lblCircuit" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Circuit"></TextView>
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText" android:id="@+id/txtCircuit"></EditText>
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/lblDriver"></TextView>
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText" android:id="@+id/txtDriver"></EditText>
<Button android:layout_width="120dip" android:text="@string/startLog" android:layout_height="57dip" android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/btnLog"></Button>
<Button android:layout_width="120dip" android:text="@string/back" android:layout_height="57dip" android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/btnBack"></Button>
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="left" android:id="@+id/txtStatus" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/lblView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="hier komt een 2D schets van het circuit  in realtime"></TextView>
  </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/lblView3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hier moet google apps zijn data weergeven"></TextView>
  <!--  <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapview1"
        android:layout_width="300dip" 
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:apiKey="0ImY2ZaoaarHlQFr4Xe0NuqRFRPvqrBOAtvX1ng"/>  -->
  </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>

</code>
```

What can be the problem ?

got the

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in the manifest
I'm running it on an avd with google maps 2.2 + addon

and my other app works fine but I cannot find differences in the use of google maps...

Comment: What error does it give you when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

hi just check whether you have include this line inside your application tag in the androidmanifest xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

also your activity should extend MapActivity instead of default Activity class...

Hope this solves your problem... If Not post your logcat...